# Changing values of list in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am new to python multiprocessing, a background about the below code. I am trying to create three processes, one to add an element to the list, one to modify element in the list, and one to print the list.

The three processes are ideally using the same list that is in shared memory, initiated using `manager`.

The problem I face is that `testprocess2` is not able to set the value to `0`, basically, it is not able to alter the list.

```
class Trade:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.exchange = None
        self.order_id = id


class testprocess2(Process):
    def __init__(self, trades, lock):
        super().__init__(args=(trades, lock))
        self.trades = trades
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            print("Altering")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                self.trades[idx].order_id = 0
            # lock.release()
            sleep(1)


class testprocess1(Process):
    def __init__(self, trades, lock):
        super().__init__(args=(trades, lock))
        self.trades = trades
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("start")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                print(self.trades[idx].order_id)

            sleep(1)


class testprocess(Process):
    def __init__(self, trades, lock):
        super().__init__(args=(trades, lock))
        self.trades = trades
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            n = random.randint(0, 9)
            print("adding random {}".format(n))
            self.trades.append(Trade(n))
            # lock.release()
            # print(trades)
            sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Manager() as manager:
        records = manager.list([Trade(5)])
        lock = Lock()

        p1 = testprocess(records, lock)
        p1.start()

        p2 = testprocess1(records, lock)
        p2.start()

        p3 = testprocess2(records, lock)
        p3.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        p3.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking your *managed* list is not in shared memory and it *is* very important to understand what is going on. The actual list holding your `Trade`  instances resides in a process that is created when you execute the `Manager()` call. When you then execute `records = manager.list([Trade(5)])`, `records` is not a direct reference to that list because, as I said, we are not dealing with shared memory. It is instead a special *proxy* object that implements the same methods as a list but when you, for example, invoke `append` on this proxy object, it takes the argument you are trying to append and serializes it and transmits it to the manager's process via either a socket or pipe where it gets de-serialized and appended to the actual list. In short, operations on the proxy object are turned into remote method calls.

Now for your problem. You are trying to reset the `order_id` attribute with the following statement:

```py
self.trades[idx].order_id = 0
```

Since we are dealing with a remote list via a proxy object, the above statements unfortunately become the equivalent of:

```py
trade = self.trades[idx] # fetch object from the remote list
trade.order_id = 0 # reset the order_id to 0 on the local copy
```

What is missing is updating the list with the newly updated trade object:

```py
self.trades[idx] = trade
```

So your single update statement really needs to be replaced with the above 3-statement sequence.

I have also taken the liberty to modify your code in several ways.

1. The [PEP8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends that class names be capitalized.
2. Since all of your process classes are identical in how they are constructed (i.e. have identical `__init__` methods), I have created an abstract base class, `TestProcess` that these classes inherit from. All they have to do is provide a `run` method.
3. I have made these process classes *daemon* classes. That means that they will terminate automatically when the main process terminates. I did this for demo purposes so that the program does not loop endlessly. The main process will terminate after 15 seconds.
4. You do not need to pass the *trades* and *lock* arguments to the `__init__` method of the `Process` class. If you were not deriving your classes from `Process` and you just wanted to, for example, have your newly created process be running a function `foo` that takes arguments *trades* and *lock*, then you would specify `p1 = Process(target=foo, args=(trades, lock))`. That is the real purpose of the `args` argument, i.e. to be used with the *target* argument. See documentation for `threading.Thread` class for details. I actually see very little value in actually deriving your classes from `multiprocessing.Process` (by not doing so there is better opportunity for *reuse*). But since you did, you are already in your `__init__` method setting instance attributes `self.trades` and `self.lock`, which will be used when your `run` method is invoked implicitly by your calling the `start` method. There is nothing further you need to do. **See the two additional code examples at the end.**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Lock
from time import sleep
import random
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Trade:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.exchange = None
        self.order_id = id


class TestProcess(Process, ABC):
    def __init__(self, trades, lock):
        Process.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.trades = trades
        self.lock = lock

    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        pass

class TestProcess2(TestProcess):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            print("Altering")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                trade = self.trades[idx]
                trade.order_id = 0
                # We must tell the managed list that it has been updated!!!:
                self.trades[idx] = trade
            # lock.release()
            sleep(1)


class TestProcess1(TestProcess):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("start")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                print(f'index = {idx}, order id = {self.trades[idx].order_id}')

            sleep(1)


class TestProcess(TestProcess):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            n = random.randint(0, 9)
            print("adding random {}".format(n))
            self.trades.append(Trade(n))
            # lock.release()
            # print(trades)
            sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Manager() as manager:
        records = manager.list([Trade(5)])
        lock = Lock()

        p1 = TestProcess(records, lock)
        p1.start()

        p2 = TestProcess1(records, lock)
        p2.start()

        p3 = TestProcess2(records, lock)
        p3.start()

        sleep(15) # run for 15 seconds
```

**Using classes not derived from `multiprocessing.Process`**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Lock
from time import sleep
import random
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Trade:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.exchange = None
        self.order_id = id


class TestProcess(ABC):
    def __init__(self, trades, lock):
        self.trades = trades
        self.lock = lock

    @abstractmethod
    def process():
        pass

class TestProcess2(TestProcess):
    def process(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            print("Altering")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                trade = self.trades[idx]
                trade.order_id = 0
                # We must tell the managed list that it has been updated!!!:
                self.trades[idx] = trade
            # lock.release()
            sleep(1)


class TestProcess1(TestProcess):
    def process(self):
        while True:
            print("start")
            for idx in range(len(self.trades)):
                print(f'index = {idx}, order id = {self.trades[idx].order_id}')

            sleep(1)


class TestProcess(TestProcess):
    def process(self):
        while True:
            # lock.acquire()
            n = random.randint(0, 9)
            print("adding random {}".format(n))
            self.trades.append(Trade(n))
            # lock.release()
            # print(trades)
            sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Manager() as manager:
        records = manager.list([Trade(5)])
        lock = Lock()

        tp = TestProcess(records, lock)
        p1 = Process(target=tp.process, daemon=True)
        p1.start()

        tp1 = TestProcess1(records, lock)
        p2 = Process(target=tp1.process, daemon=True)
        p2.start()

        tp2 = TestProcess2(records, lock)
        p3 = Process(target=tp2.process, daemon=True)
        p3.start()

        sleep(15) # run for 15 seconds
```

**Using functions instead of classes derived from `multiprocessing.Process`**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Lock
from time import sleep
import random


class Trade:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.exchange = None
        self.order_id = id


def testprocess2(trades, lock):
    while True:
        # lock.acquire()
        print("Altering")
        for idx in range(len(trades)):
            trade = trades[idx]
            trade.order_id = 0
            # We must tell the managed list that it has been updated!!!:
            trades[idx] = trade
        # lock.release()
        sleep(1)


def testprocess1(trades, lock):
    while True:
        print("start")
        for idx in range(len(trades)):
            print(f'index = {idx}, order id = {trades[idx].order_id}')

        sleep(1)


def testprocess(trades, lock):
    while True:
        # lock.acquire()
        n = random.randint(0, 9)
        print("adding random {}".format(n))
        trades.append(Trade(n))
        # lock.release()
        # print(trades)
        sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Manager() as manager:
        records = manager.list([Trade(5)])
        lock = Lock()

        p1 = Process(target=testprocess, args=(records, lock), daemon=True)
        p1.start()

        p2 = Process(target=testprocess1, args=(records, lock), daemon=True)
        p2.start()

        p3 = Process(target=testprocess2, args=(records, lock), daemon=True)
        p3.start()

        sleep(15) # run for 15 seconds
```

Comment: I very much liked the detailed explanation. On the 4th point, I am little confused. "You do not need to pass the trades and lock arguments to the __init__ method of the Process class." So, the manager does the proxy work across process, and not the argument we pass it to __init__. ?

Comment: I have updated the answer by expanding on the 4th point and I have added two additional coding examples.

Comment: "So, the manager does the proxy work across process, and not the argument we pass it to init. " Which argument to which **init**? `manager.list([Trade(5)])` creates the list and returns the proxy which you have assigned to `records`. You then pass `records` to all of your class/processes' constructors, which gets saved as `self.trades`. Every method against that proxy results in a message being sent to the manager's process where the actual method is performed against the actual list. Is that clear?

Comment: Makes sense. Yes